# Android studio show no ui when run studio.sh

Tags: android

I have download android studio 3.1,and unzip it. When I run the start up script studio.sh, No UI show up and no error log,just an icon shown on the task bar,I do not know where is wrong,any advice will be appreciate.

My system is ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Are you running from the terminal, or a file browser? If you are running from a file browser, can you try running it from the terminal and checking for output

Comment: try to delete .androidstudio_version folder from home. It is a hidden folder in the home directory.